# Separate sequence.ids for each df in a list, resulting in values of character sequence.ids

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I'm new with list logic in R.  I would like to obtain a character value of a specific column for each df in the list.

For example of one df in the list `metadata_river` for the df `Alabama` and the column `sequence_id`:

```
ex <- metadata_river$Alabama$sequence_id
```

where,

```
ex
 [1] "NASQAN2015.161.348" "NASQAN2015.162.348" "NASQAN2015.147.348" "NASQAN2015.163.348"
 [5] "NASQAN2015.148.348" "NASQAN2015.202.394" "NASQAN2015.203.394" "NASQAN2015.204.394"
 [9] "NASQAN2016.003.394" "NASQAN2016.004.394" "NASQAN2016.005.394" "NASQAN2016.006.394"
[13] "NASQAN2016.007.394" "NASQAN2016.008.394" "NASQAN2016.009.394" "NASQAN2016.010.394"
[17] "NASQAN2016.011.394" "NASQAN2016.012.394" "NASQAN2016.013.394" "NASQAN2016.014.394"
```

There are 37 different dfs (represented here as `Alabama`) and I'd like a simple way to get each column characters in individual values.  So each of the 37 dfs has it's own `ex` output.

I hope this makes sense without any example data.  I know that's a faux pas, but I hope I've explained my situation sufficiently.

Comment: Loop through dataframes and subset, see linked post, something like: `lapply(metadata_river, function(i) i[[ "sequence_id" ]])`